Condition for minimality in nonlinear system (ruling out redundant states)
I have an nth-order system and have an SS representation with n states.
$\dot{x} =f(x) , x \in R^n $
Furthermore, I can pick certain measurements:
$y=h(x), y \in R^q$
that can make the system observable in the sense that the observability gramian is full rank.
Can I claim that my representation is minimal and there are no redundant states? If not, can you come up with a counter example?
Edit:  I know controllability+observability could result in minimality in nonlinear systems in certain conditions: Kotta, Ülle, et al. "Minimal realizations of nonlinear systems." Automatica 95 (2018): 207-212.
But in my problem, I don't necessarily have controllability. However, I have the correct number of states.

What has your progress been on this problem so far? Have you considered the linear case first?

What do you mean with redundant states? At least usually in the context of minimal representation there are also inputs to the system, but in your question this is missing. Is this correct?

@RollenS.D'Souza If I could demonstrate that there are no redundant states in a locally linearized system, it would suffice, I believe.

@KwinvanderVeen By no redundant states I mean that none of my n states are linearly dependent.
Not sure if the input is needed in my problem, but if you are considering controllability, I would be interested to see what the general conclusion could be.
I know controllability+observability could result in minimality in nonlinear systems in certain conditions :
Kotta, Ülle, et al. "Minimal realizations of nonlinear systems." Automatica 95 (2018): 207-212.
But in my problem, I don't necessarily have controllability. However, I have the correct number of states.

Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "I don't necessarily have controllability"? Your system has no inputs, so it is certainly not controllable. And what do you mean with "However, I have the correct number of states"? How do you define a "correct" number of states?
